# How do I optimize this r function with a constraint?

Tags: r, optimization

```
w1 <- 1000

w2 <- 600

a <- c(w1,w2)
fun1 <- function(a){
  return(exp(1)^1.5*a[1]^0.2*a[2]^(1-0.2))
}

#constraint - a[1]+a[2]=10000

Answer1 <- constrOptim(c(w1,w2), fun1, NULL,
                       ui = c(1,1), ci = c(10000),
                       control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

Trying to optimize the function
However, getting an error

```
"Error in constrOptim(c(1, 1), fun1, NULL, ui = c(1, 1), ci = c(10000),  : 
  initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region"
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You don't need a constrained optimization here: just replace `a2` with `10000-a1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(DEoptim)

fun1 <- function(a1)
{
  a2 <- 10000 - a1
  val <- exp(1) ^ 1.5 * a1 ^ 0.2 * a2 ^ 0.8
  
  if(is.na(val) | is.nan(val))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)

  }else
  {
    return(-val)
  }  
}

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fun1, lower = 0, upper = 10000)
obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have an "equality" constraint consisting of only two variables, which actually can be denoted by `x` and `10000-x` respectively. In this case, `optim` is sufficient for your purpose, e.g.,

```
f <- function(x) {
  return(exp(1.5) * x^0.2 * (10000 - x)^(1 - 0.2))
}

optim(1000,
  f,
  method = "Brent", 
  lower = 0, 
  upper = 10000, 
  control = list(fnscale = -1)
)
```

and you will obtain

```
$par
[1] 2000

$value
[1] 27171.88

$counts
function gradient
      NA       NA

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

---

By the way, you can visualize the cost function `f` using `curve(f, 0, 10000)`, which shows

[image]